# Is Director Anton from 'De Luizenmoeder' a narcissist?

Tags: character, de-luizenmoeder

So, in the Dutch series *De Luizenmoeder*, there's a school director named Anton. I'm wondering if this character is a narcissist, after seeing how they went about the April fools jokes (they cross a lot of boundaries without apologizing but get mad when their employees take revenge and demand an apology).

Also, the way the character is put in a leading position (school director) and seems very convinced that they are always right, together with the fact that they steal plans but blame bad outcomes on others makes me all think that Anton may be a narcissist.

**Was this character meant to be a narcissist?**

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this goes as an answer, but anyway I watched the [clip: De 1 april grap voor Anton (De Luizenmoeder)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UL1673sG7rM), but not the whole series.

Seems to me he's the typical anti-hero behaving unethically. He is used by the screenwriter to create tension by penetrating the culturally defined boundaries of political correctness. It  may represent a *[deconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconstruction)* of the present socio-political climate. I don't think the script writer intended him to be a narcissist.